# React - Data not found

Tags: reactjs, object

I have a main component `Resume` and a child called `Header`:

```js
class Resume extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
          data: {}
        }
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState( this.state = data);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="Resume">
            <Header data={this.state.header} />
            <Skills data={this.state.skills} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Resume;

    class Header extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="header">
            <h1>{JSON.stringify(this.props.data.title)}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

```
My simple sample data so far is: 

{
  "header": {
    "title": "Tim Smith's Resume"
  },
  "skills": [
    {"name": "HTML", "duration": 14}
  ]
}
```

Why am I getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: {JSON.stringify(this.props.data)} renders {"title":"Tim Smith's Resume"}

Comment: Where does `data` in `componentDidMount()` come from? Is it defined somewhere in the file that you haven't shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No need to use `JSON#stringify` your title property is already a string.
2. In your `componentDidMount` is not like that we are setting state. Try to use

   `componentDidMount() 
       const data = {}; // Define data or get it like you want
       this.setState({
           ...data
       });
   }`
3. In your constructor where you initialize your state. You have to do `this.state = { header: {}, skills: {} }` not what you done.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not setting the state of the `<Resume/>` component correctly. Try the following adjustment:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    // This will set the `data` field of your component state, to the 
    // value of the `data` variable.

    this.setState({ data : data });
  }
```